# How does one store CSS in a Django class?

Tags: python, css, django, django-templates

I am in the brainstorming phase of writing a Django app to output html5 slideshow presentations. I would like to be able to define a style with each slide object (and probably also a default value for the presentation object) which would simply be css defining colors, sizes. etc. Ultimately, what I want to be able to do is create functions that output the presentation to arbitrary presentation frameworks, such as deck.js or fathom.js, for example.

I've just typed out a very rough draft of my app model:

```
from django.db import models
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField

class Presentation(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()

class Slide(models.Model):
    title = models.Charfield()
    header = RichTextField()
    footer = RichTextField()
    presentation = models.ForeignKey(Presentation)
    slide_number = models.IntegerField() 
    audio = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)
    style = models.ForeignKey(SlideStyle)

class SlideSegment(models.Model):
    slide = models.ForeignKey(Slide)
    duration = models.IntegerField() # duration of slide segment in ms
    position = models.SmallIntegerField() # to order segments
    content = RichTextField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['position']

class SlideStyle(models.Model):
    name = Charfield()
    css = ???
```

My first idea was to create a TextField or UrlField to store some CSS, but I immediately began identifying issues with this.

Leveraging Django's template system seems like the Django way to do this, what with separating data from presentation and all. But, then how would I manage these styles so that an admin using the django admin interface can create/delete styles and choose a style when creating a slides?

Comment: I am not sure if you can do it on a model, but a form for sure: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/topics/forms/media/#media-as-a-dynamic-property

Answer (score 1):

A "style" usually requires more than just a css file - multiple css files, background images, eventually fonts etc.

If "styles" are to be uploable then a possible solution might be to use a FileField accepting a zip, required to contain at least "style.css" file as entry point. Then on upload the file would be unzipped in /styles/ and the SlideStyle model would grow a "style_url" property returning the appropriate url...

My 2 cents.